# MATLAB- 2D DFT very slow

Tags: matlab, fft, dft

I have to wrie my own 2D DFT and I'm currently using this

```
for l=0:1:m-1
for k=0:1:n-1
    for x=0:1:n-1
        for y=0:1:m-1
            a=x+1;b=y+1;
            c= im3(a,b) * exp(-1i*2*pi*(k*x/n + l*y/m));
            c1=c1+c;
        end
    end
    aa=l+1;bb=k+1;
    im(bb,aa)=c1;
    c1=0;
end
end
```

It works fine for smaller images but when the pixel dimensions or the array gets bigger it gets insanely slow. Can anyone help?

the `im3`is the array that has the pixel values stored and `im` is the one that stores the values after the algorithm executes

Comment: Have you preallocated `im`, or does it already exist in the workspace before the loops?

Comment: Yea, I took care of that already.

Comment: Have you considered using an [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) and [vectorizing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) your code? Note that, although you tagged your post as "FFT", you do not appear to be using one.

Comment: You use too many loops, try to avoid at least two of them using matrix manipulations. It will speed up your code. Another point, it you have parallel computing toolbox, try to use parfor in the case if you have more than one core on your computer

Answer (score 0):

To compute 2D DFT you need to compute DFT for rows, and then for cols. 
Try out this code

```
f1=imread('Lady.tif')
[M1,N1]=size(f1)
 DFT=exp(sqrt(-1)*2*pi*(n).*(k)./512);

%img=x.';
F1R=zeros(M1,N1); F1RC=zeros(M1,N1);

for row=1:M1;


 x=f1(row,:)';

 F1R(row,:)=((DFT*x)');


end
%%part one

for col=1:N;


 x=F1R(:,col);

 F1RC(:,col)=((DFT'*x));


end
```

Btw, fft2 should get you 2D DFT too

Check out this link
http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/discrete-fourier-transform.html